# lineBuffer in C++

Tags: c++

I was just browsing some coding stuff and noticed this code:

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  ifstream file;
  string lineBuffer;
  file.open(argv[1]) ;  
  while (!file.eof()) 
  {
     getline(file, lineBuffer);
     if (lineBuffer.length() == 0)
       continue; //ignore all empty lines
     else 
     {
        //do your code here
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have searched for the concept of a `lineBuffer` all over the net but found no relevant answer.
Can anyone help me to understand how `lineBuffer` is used to read a file line by line?

Comment: The code snippet you posted does read lines sequentially from a file, so you answered your own question.

Comment: `lineBuffer` is just a string. Isn't it `getline` that you need to stufy?

Comment: thanks david i got this much by looking at code bt not actuly gtng how to get throug i mens wit lineBufeer normal console are not working

Comment: Don;t do this `while (!file.eof()) `

Answer (score 2):

```
string lineBuffer;
```

This is a variable called `lineBuffer`. It's not a concept to be understood and it doesn't read files, it's just a string with a name, it could just as easily have been called:

```
string fred;
```

but because it is used as a buffer to hold each line of text, it is more sensible and helpful to call it `lineBuffer`.

Wherever you found that code, stop reading it, the code is broken and written by someone who doesn't know C++ very well. This part is broken:

```
while (!file.eof()) 
{
   getline(file, lineBuffer);
```

It should be done like this instead:

```
while (getline(file, lineBuffer))
{
```

Comment: I'd rather say that reading from file is done in inappropriate way than calling this code "broken".

Comment: And I'd rather say using `while (!file.eof()` is broken **and it must stop**

Comment: @LihO It's broken, in the sense that the code doesn't work (at least for any reasonable definition of work).

Comment: Well, I agree with this answer, I just found it a bit odd and disrespectful to author of that code, whoever it was.

Comment: If code is broken and obviously not tested properly then it doesn't deserve respect. I could have been far more disrespectful than saying "doesn't know C++ very well"

Answer (score 0):

The `lineBuffer` is a string where you are asking C++ to put the line it reads. Once the line is in that string, they check whether there was any content in that line, and if not, skip processing it.